# How do I pass a variable from parent to forked child process?

Tags: node.js, electron

My parent process forks the child as so:

```
child = new fork('child.js');
```

Now in my parent process, I have a variable that contains an array. I want to pass this array to the child process so I have tried to send the variable as a message to the child:

```
//in parent.js
var jData = ['pro1', 'pro2', 'pro3']
child.send({'koota': jData})
//


//in child.js
process.on('koota', (jData) => {
    console.log(jData + ' from child!')
})
//
```

However, this does not work. What method is there to pass the array to the child so I can use it's contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `process.on('message', () => {})` to [receive messages](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#event-message) that have been [sent](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#subprocesssendmessage-sendhandle-options-callback) with `child.send({})`.

Adapted from the linked documentation page (shortened, see original for full example):

```js
const { fork } = require('child_process');
const child = fork('child.js'); // no need for 'new'
const jData = ['pro1', 'pro2', 'pro3'];
child.send({'koota': jData});
```

child.js:

```js
process.on('message', (msg) => {
    if (msg.koota) {
        console.log(msg.koota, 'from child!');
    }
});
```

You are currently using `process.on(<a custom name, not "message">)`. You can simply check what 'type' of message you receive in the event handler:

```
process.on('message', (msg) => { 
  if (msg.koota) {
    // ...
  }
})
```

Sending a message like `{type: 'koota', data: {}}` would probably look nicer (`if(msg.type === 'koota') {...}`).